# Overriding native HLS support breaks smooth playback on safari with videojs-contrib-hls

Tags: macos, safari, streaming, video.js

I am playing HLS content using with [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js)  along with [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) plugin. I'am using [videojs-contrib-qualitylevels](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels) plugin to get the ABR list.

I am able to successfully get the ABR list on Windows-10 Chrome/Firefox/IE11/Edge. But I am not able to get the ABR list on MAC safari-12.0

I used following options

- videojs.options.hls.overrideNative = true
- videojs.options.html5.nativeAudioTracks = false
- videojs.options.html5.nativeVideoTracks= false

For these options I am getting the ABR list on Mac safari but after using these options video playback is not smooth, after seeking it's taking time to update the current frame.

Attached screenshots for further details [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14beD4BKcjvoUCyJALaOKWBtWv8QrQb_g/view?usp=sharing), [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Scu2RUGWRRihe9GHr1vwZarJSoxPfnRq/view?usp=sharing).

This is the player test page code snippet

```
   this._player = videojs(this._nativeInstanceId, {
        html5: {
            nativeAudioTracks: false,
            nativeVideoTracks: false,
            hls: {
                overrideNative: true
            }
        }
    });
```

The playback is not smooth. On seek, frames are taking time to render properly

Comment: I had a similar problem like yours. But I associate the phenomenon that you describe using macOS on a virtual machine. Do you run macOS on a real machine?